# What is an alternative to a Data Table Class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a simple app using Flutter. I'm trying to add rows to my app. If any of you know Swift, I'm basically trying to achieve what a TableView does in Swift. I've looked at the flutter documents, but a "Data Table class" doesn't seem to give me the desired look or functionality. I was wondering if anyone knows how I can implement this feature without re-writing the whole main.dart file. Does anyone have any tips? Any pointers would be appreciated.

[This is what a TableView does in Swift. I need the same outcome, but in Dart syntax.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAEYU.png)

Here is my code in the main.dart file:

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:testing_stuff_ignore/new_screen.dart';

 void main() {
 runApp(const MyApp());
 }

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 const MyApp({super.key});

 // This widget is the root of your application.
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
    useMaterial3: true,
  ),
  home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
 );
  }
    }

 class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

 final String title;

 @override
 State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
// int _counter = 0; //Ignore any "counter" references.

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    title: Center(
      child: Text(
        'Test (Beta v1)',
      ),
    ),
   ),
  body: Center(
    // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
    // in the middle of the parent.
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Text(
          'This page is where I need those rows',
        ),
        Text(
          '',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NewScreen()),
      );
    },
    // onPressed: _incrementCounter,
    tooltip: 'Increment',
    child: const Icon(
      Icons.add,
      color: Colors.yellow,
    ),
  ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
);
 }
```

}

I've looked through the Flutter Docs and tried adding Rows, but that didn't work. I'm sure there is something in the Docs, but I did not find anything as of yet.

Comment: Tried ListView?

Comment: Well, no. I totally forgot about ListView, apologies. Where would I add it? Replace the Column() with ListView()? (Just wanting to make sure).

Comment: If you load a data set: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists or https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/mixed-list. If not, https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer that worked for me:

```
 child: ListView(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    const Text(
      'This page is where I need those rows',
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? I have not tried the code, but should be in the ballpark of what you want. The FloatingButtons is not added below. Use Expanded within row to make "table cells".

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
        Center(
            child: Text('Test (Beta v1)',),
        ),  
        ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
                 Row()...
                 Text('', style: 
                     Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,),
            ]
        ),

    ]),
};
```